# Unicorn+Nginx+Sinatra based VPS with master worker failed

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy a Sinatra application to my server with Unicorn. However when I try to run `unicorn -c path/to/unicorn.rb -E development -D` I got `master failed to start, check stderr log for details` error. Here is the stderr log file:

```
FATAL -- : error adding listener addr=../rails/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb:167:in `bind_listen': Don't know how to bind: ../rails/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock (Argum$
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:255:in `listen'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:801:in `block in bind_new_listeners!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:801:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:801:in `bind_new_listeners!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:146:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Also, I created unicorn tmp,log,tmp/pid,tmp/sockets folders inside my application folder and created unicorn.conf and unicorn.rb as following:

**unicorn.rb**

```
 # set path to app that will be used to configure unicorn,
# note the trailing slash in this example
@dir = "./"

worker_processes 2
working_directory @dir

timeout 30

# Specify path to socket unicorn listens to,
# we will use this in our nginx.conf later
listen "#{@dir}tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Set process id path
pid "#{@dir}tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"

# Set log file paths
stderr_path "#{@dir}log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{@dir}log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

**unicorn.conf**

```
listen "127.0.0.1:8080"
worker_processes 2
user "rails"
working_directory "./"
pid "/home/unicorn/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/home/unicorn/log/unicorn.log"
```

I assumed the problem might based on nginx. so I edited nginx.conf as following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css text/comma-separated-values;
        upstream app_server { server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0; }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        upstream unicorn_server {
                server unix:/home/rails/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
                fail_timeout=0;
        }
}
```

As can be seen from the logs, the problem is based on the unicorn.sock file. However when I googled the problem about "Don't know how to bind" there is no solution that I can found. Need advice(s). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

According to the code of `socket_helper.rb` (see [here](https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn/socket_helper.rb)), it might be an issue with the socket path format in your `unicorn.rb` file.

The comments before the `bind_listen` method say :

```
# creates a new server, socket. address may be a HOST:PORT or
# an absolute path to a UNIX socket. address can even be a Socket
# object in which case it is immediately returned
def bind_listen(address = '0.0.0.0:8080', opt = {})
  ...
end
```

So I guess you **must** use an absolute path for your socket, instead of a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

@PA. Buisson is correct, and led me to the solution. For completeness, the unicorn.rb can be changed to:

```
# set path to app that will be used to configure unicorn,
# note the trailing slash in this example
@dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

worker_processes 2
working_directory @dir

timeout 30

# Specify path to socket unicorn listens to,
# we will use this in our nginx.conf later
listen File.join(@dir, "tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock"), :backlog => 64

# Set process id path
pid File.join(@dir, "tmp/pids/unicorn.pid")

# Set log file paths
stderr_path File.join(@dir, "log/unicorn.stderr.log")
stdout_path File.join(@dir, "log/unicorn.stdout.log")
```